# How can I get the absolute path of my Perl program from its relative path?

Tags: perl, relative-path

I need to find the full path to the Perl script I'm currently running, i.e.

- for ~/dir/my.pl I would need it to be "/home/user/dir/my.pl". The `$0` will give me "~/dir/my.pl".
- for ./my.pl I would still need "/home/user/dir/my.pl"

etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [FindBin](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?FindBin) module:

```
$ cat /tmp/foo/bar/baz/quux/prog
#! /usr/bin/perl

use FindBin;

print "$FindBin::Bin/$FindBin::Script\n";

$ PATH=/tmp/foo/bar/baz/quux prog
/tmp/foo/bar/baz/quux/prog

$ cd /tmp/foo/bar/baz/quux

$ ./prog 
/tmp/foo/bar/baz/quux/prog
```

Comment: looks like it's giving me empty $FindBin::Bin, though

Comment: How are you running your program?

Comment: just ./my.pl, and it has #!/usr/bin/perl in it

Comment: FindBin has known issues (http://search.cpan.org/~tty/kurila-1.19_0/lib/FindBin.pm#KNOWN_ISSUES), so are you running into one of them?

Comment: FindBin has issues and if you have ~/bin/script.pl -> ~/scripts/script.pl then after executing script.pl $FindBin::Bin contains ~/bin instead of ~/scripts/. You need to use &File::Basename::dirname($Cwd::realpath($0)) for real parent directory of a script.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you're looking for the [rel2abs function in File::Spec](http://search.cpan.org/~smueller/PathTools-3.30/lib/File/Spec.pm#rel2abs()).  For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use File::Spec;
my $location = File::Spec->rel2abs($0);
print "$location\n";
```

This will resolve $0 in the way you describe:

```
$ ./myfile.pl
/Users/myname/myfile.pl
$ ~/myfile.pl
/Users/myname/myfile.pl
```

Alternatively, you could use [Cwd::abs_path](http://search.cpan.org/~smueller/PathTools-3.30/Cwd.pm) in the exact same way.

Comment: unfortunately no, it won't. This implies you're in the same directory you were when the call was made. It may or may not be so

Comment: Hmm... no it doesn't...?  `$ export PATH=~/; cd /tmp/; myfile.pl' ->
/Users/myname/myfile.pl

Comment: I mean that myfile.pl, being a complicated program, could have cd-ed after it has been called but before it tries to resolve the path. Then it would resolve to /newdir/myfile.pl if called as ./myfile.pl

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at [FindBin](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?FindBin) or [FindBin::Real](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?FindBin::Real).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just need to expand the paths to their absolute values.  Check [this article](http://www.chovy.com/personal/converting-paths-to-absolute-in-perl/) for how to do that.

Comment: you can't expand ./my.pl to anything unless you know where you were (i.e. CWD) at the time the call was made

Comment: This also doesn't handle tilde expansion.

Answer (score 0):

Use FindBin Module

Answer (score 0):

Many of the concepts mentioned will break in case that the file itself is a symbolic link. I usually start my scripts in the following way:

```
use strict;
use English;
use warnings;

use Cwd qw(realpath);
use File::Basename;
use lib &File::Basename::dirname(&Cwd::realpath($PROGRAM_NAME));
```

Hopefully this helps.